# How to model entities without unneeded variables to save memory and reduce db calls?

Tags: java, database, oop, clean-architecture

I have recently read about Clean Architecture and I'm trying to create classes for entities.

Let's take YouTube for example. When I want to display the name and subscriber count of a YouTube channel (e.g. when viewing a list of subscriptions), I have my classes as follows:

```java
class Channel {
  private String name;
  private int subscriberCount;
  private List<Video> videos;
}

class Video { // data variables about Video }
```

The problem I have is that whenever I want to fetch channel data from my database to create a Channel entity, the Channel entity must contain all the videos that belong to the channel. But I do not need to display the list of videos of the YouTube channel, so preferably I do not want to retrieve video information from the database. (Viewing a list of 200 subscribed channels, each having 1000 videos = 200,000 video object that I do not use)

How do I model my classes to make sure that each class has only the information that I need (so I do not waste memory and db calls? I am thinking to (1) set `videos` as null, or (2) create a new class without the `videos` variable, or (3) store only the IDs of the videos, making the variable have a type of `List<int>`.

Comment: Your Channel class is fine.  Just set the name and subscriber count in the constructor, and use a set method to set the video list.  That way, your code decides whether or not you need the video list.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I am afraid that I accidentally try to retrieve videos but it is null for some Channels

Comment: As always, in software development, the answer is: _it depends_. In your case, it depends on what you need to do with the list of videos. For example, do you have to send `Channel` objects from a server to a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Channel entity must contain all the videos that belong to the channel

It must not. You can also define the `Channel` without the videos

```
class Channel {
  private String name;
  private int subscriberCount;
}
```

and fetch the `Video` via an own `VideoRepository`.

```
interface VideoRepository {
    public List<Video> getChannelVideos(Channel channel);
}
```

Then you have full control over the video loading and thus memory consumption.

you can also add paging to you repository

```
interface VideoRepository {
    public List<Video> getChannelVideos(Channel channel, int offset, int size);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a `Channel` class that looks like this:

```
public class Channel {
    private String name;
    private int subscriberCount;
    private List<Video> videos;

    public Channel(String name, int subscriberCount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.subscriberCount = subscriberCount;
        this.videos = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<Video> getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }

    public void setVideos(List<Video> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getSubscriberCount() {
        return subscriberCount;
    }

}

public class Video { // data variables about Video };
```

By creating the `List` of videos in the constructor, but not adding to the `List` unless you execute the `setVideos` method, you'll never get a null response when you execute the `getVideos` method.

You'll get an empty `List`.